# How to define custom preprocessor macros in xconfig file when using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I has created two configurations in Project > Project name > Info (tab) > Configurations Target.
Let's call em `CustomDebug` and `CustomRelease`. For each configuration, i has created xconfig files – `CustomDebug.xconfig` and `CustomRelease.xconfig` and set em as 'Base on Configuration File' field to corresponding configurations. After that i did run `pod install`. Pods has been installed with warnings – I should use config files generated by pods directly in my configs or by including em in my config files. So i choose 2nd option and add corresponding includes to my config files.

All works fine. But...
I tried to define custom macro in my config file:

`GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='$(value) MACRO=1'`

And it overrides same var from config file generated by pods.

`GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1 $(inherited) GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS=1 $(inherited) PB_FIELD_32BIT=1 PB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS=1 PB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1`

When i swap the import and custom macro lines, obviously, value defined in pods config for `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` overrides my one.

Does any body know, how to "extend" value of `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` defined in config file generated by CocoaPods?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "extend" value of GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS defined in config file generated by CocoaPods.

To fix nanopb framework in Pods, add to Podfile post-install script:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
    
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          if target.name == "nanopb"
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'PB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1'
          end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Didn't ask about `nanopb` but anyway it looks like option to set custom macro. Will try.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(inherited)`:

`GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='$(inherited) $(value) MACRO=1'`

Comment: Already tried. It doesn’t work for configs with same level.